# inadaptable vs. unadaptable / inadapted vs. unadapted

Tags: vocabulary

Is there any difference in meaning between "inadaptable" and "unadaptable"?

Is one of them used more frequently?

Thank you.

PS: How about "inadapted" vs. "unadapted"?

Answer (score 1):

**Inadaptable** and **unadaptable** are semantically same, you can use them alternatively.
Inadaptable-that can't be changed to suit different situations/conditions/uses.(Not adaptable)
Unadaptable-that can't be changed to suit different situations/conditions/uses.(Not adaptable)

Comment: Can you flesh out your answer a bit, maybe source it?

Comment: How about inadapted vs. unadapted? Autocorrect in word processing software does not accept them and there are almost no instances of their use in books / newspapers.

Comment: To my ear, the adjective "inadapted" sounds a bit off. I'd almost certainly say "unadapted".  "Inadaptable", on the other hand, is fine.  The term "ill-adapted" does exist, though.  In fact, it's quite common. I've never heard "ill-adaptable." ;-)